# Catch rate control

Tags: c, append, tracking, backtracking

Catch rate for analog input

I have a linear pot voltage I am feeding into an analog input on a Teensy board. If the value for the linear pot gets smaller too fast I would like to override it with a controlled fixed rate. I was going to use a 500 element array to track and make sure the potentiometer value does not go in the negative direction too quickly but then realize arrays in C are not as easy as python, so now I am sort of stuck. if I base the tracking off the immediate previous value it most likely will be read too quick so I was going to have the first element compared to the 500th and the pseudo code would look like this:

```
const int pwmPin = 5; 
const int pwmFrequency = 15000; 
const int pwmResolution = 8; 


int analogPin = A5; // potentiometer wiper (middle terminal) connected to analog pin 3
                    // outside leads to ground and +3V
float AdjVal = 0;  // variable to store the value read
int RawVal = 0;
int LatsVals[500];

int startingDC = 90; // set starting DC: 109.65 = 43% DC



void setup() { 
  pinMode(pwmPin, OUTPUT);  //set pinMode
  analogWriteFrequency (pwmPin, pwmFrequency); //set PWM Frequency
  analogWriteResolution (pwmResolution); //set analog resolution

    }


void loop() {            
     // Set the PWM duty cycle 
  RawVal = analogRead(analogPin); //read raw value to control for-loop
  AdjVal = analogRead(analogPin)/16;  //reduce anaolog reading to be able to add it starting duty cycle and fit within 1023 down to 255

//control loop:
  if (lastVal[0] - lastVal[500] > 50 && sizeof(LastVals) = 500) { //if rate of change is >50cnts
    for(RawVal < 1023){ //control rate of change and come to complete stop
        analogWrite(pwmPin, RawVal); 
        RwaVal = RawVal + 1;  
    }
  } else {
    analogWrite(pwmPin, startingDC + AdjVal); //else just continue to write everything to pwmPin (0-255 range)
  }

  if (sizeof(LastVals) = 500){ //clear LastVals every 500 cnts
      for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof LastVals; ++i)
          LastVals[i] = 0;
      
  }

counter = counter + 1;
  //otherwise just keep tracking previous values
strcat(LastVals[counter], RawVal)

    // Code for other tasks, if any 
}
```

and the closet post to my problem is:

[How to calculate the rate of change of a variable over time in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961215/how-to-calculate-the-rate-of-change-of-a-variable-over-time-in-c)

so I will try to apply their steps till further progress is made here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code in a pseudo-code that is closer to C:

```
const int       pwmPin = 5;
const int       pwmFrequency = 15000;
const int       pwmResolution = 8;


int             analogPin = A5;
/* potentiometer wiper(middle terminal) connected to analog pin 3 */
/* outside      leads to ground and + 3 V */
float           AdjVal = 0;
/* variable to store the value read */
int             RawVal = 0;
#define N 500
int             LastVals[N];

int             startingDC = 90;
/* set starting DC:109.65 = 43 % DC */



void
setup()
{
        pinMode(pwmPin, OUTPUT);
        /* set pinMode */
        analogWriteFrequency(pwmPin, pwmFrequency);
        /* set PWM Frequency */
        analogWriteResolution(pwmResolution);
        /* set analog resolution */
}


void
loop()
{
        static int last = 0;
        static int cur  = 1;

        /* Set the PWM duty cycle */
        RawVal = analogRead(analogPin);
        /* read raw value to control for -loop */
        AdjVal = analogRead(analogPin) / 16;
        /*
         * reduce anaolog reading to be able to add it starting duty cycle
         * and fit within 1023 down to 255
         */

        /* control loop: */
        if (lastVal[cur] - lastVal[last] > 50) {
                /* if rate of change    is > 50 cnts */
                for (; RawVal < 1023; RawVal++) {
                        /* control rate of change and come to complete stop */
                        analogWrite(pwmPin, RawVal);
                }
        } else {
                analogWrite(pwmPin, startingDC + AdjVal);
        }
        LastVals[cur++] = RawVal;
        if (cur >= 500) cur = 0;
        if (++last >= 500) last = 0;
}
```

Sorry about the indent change; to make it legible, I ran it through "indent".
But the basic idea is that *cur* and *last* are followers through an array, although given what you are doing, it seems like you only need the *last value* not a history.

As to what you are doing, to me it looks suspiciously like you should be using a PID-loop; that is a fancy filter that simultaneously weights the response by Proportional (immediate), Integral (historical area under curve), and Differential (rate of change).   You appear to be using a PI controller; which is fine, but you don't need to store more history than 1 to do that.

Comment: No worries, looks great. Like you mention in the last sentence of your first passage, if I added Integral and Differential control, which I do not know how to conceptualize in C for single analog pin, would also work. Then in the last sentence of the second passage, you do hint on how I am sort of executing proportional control.

Comment: Good, I live for upvotes.   There are lots of resources on these sorts of controllers; but the *ugly* is in the coefficients and set-points.   While they are conceptually simple, they are the heart of the PLC, and folks get paid very large amounts to tune them appropriately.   The good news is that a well tuned PLC can outstrip a human controller for most of these tasks; and has since the 1970s.